# Some mesh-edges in object-mode aren't displayed

Tags: modeling, interface, objects

So I have been extruding a cube to make a low poly banana and when I go from edit to object mode half the edges don't appear as well as half is dark.

[image]

[image]

I tried looking for an solution couldn't find one and its making me feel like I am doing something wrong so I decided to come here.

Comment: Mirror modifier?

Comment: The normals look like they are switched. Tab into edit mode, press A to select all, and then press Ctrl+N.

Answer (score 9):

This is normal, as you are in wireframe mode. By default not all edges are displayed in wireframe mode.

To display all edges, enable *Draw All Edges* in *Properties > Object > Display*:

[image]

Or you could switch to solid view by pressing <kbd>Z</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

What you are experiencing is normal behavior.  Unless you have certain modifiers that add geometry (subsurf, remesh, etc.) Blender will not show edges between nearly coplanar faces in order to make viewing easier.  The reason that the edges are showing on the left end of the banana is because the normals are flipped, that is why the faces are darker as well.

Normals basically tell Blender what direction the faces point.  To fix the normals you can select the faces with flipped normal and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> > *flip normals*, or select all (<kbd>A</kbd>), and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normal.

Comment: the different grayscale shades across the polygons in Edit mode do look a lot like inverted normals.