# How to display all mesh wire in flats faces?

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, wireframe

I want to display all wire in a mesh, but if the edges are in a flat face that are not shown... Here's a little example:

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some mesh-edges in object-mode aren't displayed](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21150/some-mesh-edges-in-object-mode-arent-displayed)

Comment: @gandalf3   this is not a dupicate... that thread is about normals, and this one is about wireframe

Comment: The other question's screenshot shows that the normals are flipped, but the question itself seems to be about the wireframe (judging by the title).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You need to use the draw all edges checkbox.** It is directly under the wire checkbox!

[image]