# topology broken after extruding the mesh

Tags: modeling

Its a very simple question, I am not sure what will be the impact of this on rigging & animation of my Organic Model. I was trying to extruding the circle and when I switched from Edit mode to object mode, I found that the mesh is broken (refer ciruclar mesh)

Does it have impact on my rigging & animation & or any other stage (like UV mapping)[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21150/some-mesh-edges-in-object-mode-arent-displayed

Comment: you are right, thanks  , it helped.. i am learning blender at 7 yrs, so plz excuse for simple question.. Tq

Comment: true.. i tried to search, but could not get solution, so i posted.. anyways thanks, pl post your answer.. or shall i flag this ?

Comment: The post will get closed as a duplicate if others agree it is. Alternatively, if you see the button shown [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250930/311571) on your question you can mark it as a duplicate yourself. If you don't, not to worry, you don't have to do anything.